# Bootstrap Tab Responsiva

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estou com umas tabs e quero deixar responsiva. Achei um exemplo no codepen, utilizando a versão 3.3 do Bootstrap. No projeto que estou concertando, usaram a 4.0.0-alpha-6.

**OBS.: VISUALIZAR COM A TELA MENOR QUE 480px, só aplica a regra quando for mobile.**

LINK ORIGINAL: https://codepen.io/d3rsonbr/pen/PRJrmm

No meu caso, fiz algumas mudanças, e está funcionando quando avança as TABS, mas quando clica para voltar, não funciona. Se alguem puder me ajudar.

```
<ul id="mytabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-responsive" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_1">
            <span class="text">Menu 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item next">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_2">
            <span class="text">Menu 2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_3">
            <span class="text">Menu 3</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_4">
            <span class="text">Menu 4</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu_5">
            <span class="text">Menu 5</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="menu_1">
        MENU 1
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane next" id="menu_2">
        MENU 2
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="menu_3">
        MENU 3
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="menu_4">
        MENU 4
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="menu_5">
        MENU 5
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {

    .nav-tabs-responsive > li {
        display: none;
        width: 23%;
    }

  .nav-tabs-responsive > li > a {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .nav-tabs-responsive > li.active {
    width: 54%;
  }
  .nav-tabs-responsive > li.active:first-child {
    margin-left: 23%;
  }
  .nav-tabs-responsive > li.active, .nav-tabs-responsive > li.prev, .nav-tabs-responsive > li.next {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-tabs-responsive > li.prev, .nav-tabs-responsive > li.next {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  .nav-tabs-responsive > li.next > a, .nav-tabs-responsive > li.prev > a {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
  }
  .nav-tabs-responsive > li.next > a .text, .nav-tabs-responsive > li.prev > a .text {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-tabs-responsive > li.next > a:after, .nav-tabs-responsive > li.next > a:after, .nav-tabs-responsive > li.prev > a:after, .nav-tabs-responsive > li.prev > a:after {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
  .nav-tabs-responsive > li.prev > a:after {
    content: "\f053";
  }
  .nav-tabs-responsive > li.next > a:after {
    content: "\f054";
  }
}
```

E o JS:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.tab', ' [data-toggle="tab"]', function(e) {


                    var $target = $(e.target);
                    var $tabs = $target.closest('.nav-tabs-responsive');

                    var $current = $target.closest('li');
                    var $next = $current.next();
                    var $prev = $current.prev();

                    $tabs.find('>li').removeClass('next prev');
                    $tabs.find('>li>a').removeClass('active');

                    $current.addClass('active');

                    $prev.addClass('prev');
                    $next.addClass('next');
          $('.prev a').removeClass('active');
                    $('.next a').removeClass('active');

});
```

LINK CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/d3rsonbr/pen/xWPGrz

Comment: Como assim "clica para voltar" eu testei a navegação pelas Tabs e está normal...

Comment: Esqueci de mensionar que tem que mudar a visualização para mobile, ou menor que 480px